# Cannot connect to localhost on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, connection

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to localhost.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-2-database-engine-error

---

The system cannot find the file specified

---

I tried to connect the server
Added a new connection
also tried starting the service from the services manager